Change Data Capture - Strategies for subsequent updates if delete fails
I have a system that listens to events from thirdparty data source. The events are basically changes to data or records (Change Data Capture or CDC). This would be rare, however, remains a possibility. What to do if system gets delete event (on deleting a record), and fails to process it. But then subsequently sees updates on the same record. What are possible strategies to handle such a situation?
